# my thread was moderated incorrectly

Tags: support, moderation

I'm not familiar with stack overflow and its etiquette. Sorry! I was helping a user on this thread: [Why does my Mail App for Office show in Outlook online but not in my installed Outlook Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965701/why-does-my-mail-app-for-office-show-in-outlook-online-but-not-in-my-installed-o/25979374#25979374) with his problem. Mistakenly, I posted my question as an answer, instead of in the comments section. My answer got deleted, and my reputation dropped, so I couldn't comment on the question anymore.

I can actually help this person - I know what's going on. But since my reputation is now below 50, how can I help him?

I undeleted my answer and was helping him in the comments section of my answer, but then @ChrisF deleted it again, even though I posted the actual correct answer there (he was using wrong version of the client).

Now this guy is completely stuck, and I can't help.

Comment: We don't have threads. We have *questions*, with associated answers. This is an important distinction!

Comment: Now that you have what you needed, [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25979374/edit), convert it into something of an answer (even if not 100% correct), and flag to have  it undeleted.  From that point, the OP and you can get more clarification in the comments on your answer.

Comment: thanks, updated it! do i have to click "undelete" on it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and suggestions, everyone! Yea, I couldn't come up with a good title for this post... Help me get my reputation up high enough, so I can help someone out? :)

Answer (score 11):

Your post was *not* an answer. You mentioned a potential answer in the comments, but you never edited it into your actual answer. It was first deleted as not-an-answer from the review queue, properly, and then after a moderator flag was handled, it was again (properly) deleted.

You can edit it into an actual answer, and it should get undeleted if so. You can flag your post as "Other", and explain your improvements. A moderator will review it.

Comment: They'll have to flag it to be undeleted though. This doesn't automagically happen.

Comment: thanks, can i flag it, or does a moderator have to?

Comment: @AndrewS You would put in the flag, so moderators can see it. However, in *this* case, since I already am aware of the post, I want and checked it out. I've restored it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber btw, the reason why I didn't edit my answer immediately, is because I was still collecting more info at first. I was stuck in a catch-22 - I did the wrong thing in asking my question in the answer, but once someone downvoted it, I couldn't post anything in the comment section to the original question. And then once a diamond moderator deleted the answer entirely, I couldn't even comment in the comment section under my answer.